# Install nodes error (could not find kernel image)

Tags: maas

I am just starting to test MAAS. I installed ubuntu 13.04 i386 server with maas option, modified /etc/maas/import_pxe_files to add raring to RELEASES (also import_ephemerals), and ran maas-import-pxe-files, no error returned.

When I try to install a node, it gets an ip from maas-dhcp, and tries to boot from tftp but then the following error appears:

Could not find kernel image: i386/generic/raring/commissioning/linux

I looked for the files in /var/lib/maas/tftp, but from there the only path to the image is i386/generic/raring/install/linux

Note, "install" instead of "commissioning"

I somehow found that there is a "purpose" option for some tftp python scripts, with possible values "install" or "commissioning",  but i dont know how to change it, or how can i say that the images are in the "install" directory

Or what i am missing, did i miss a step to properly configure nodes installation?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you added 'amd64' or 'i386' as the ARCH.  You need to add ARCH as 'i386/generic' or 'amd64/generic' in /etc/maas/import_ephemerals

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it. In import_pxe_files the values in ARCHES were correct. In import_ephemerals i just uncommented ARCHES, but there only said "amd64 i386". When i added the "/generic" part, the error was gone.

Comment: But then there was another error: it founds linux and initrd.gz but it hangs in Loading initrd.gz....... `Boot failed: press a key to retry, or wait for reset...`

Answer (score 0):

same problem to me.
i just add soft link in /var/lib/maas/tftp/amd64/generic/precise

`cd /var/lib/maas/tftp/amd64/generic/precise`


and

`sudo sudo ln -s install commissioning`

Answer (score 0):

I also got error like "could not find kernel image : i386/generic//install/linux " while booting node after pressing start node button via GUI. I found that this error caused because I didn't choose Release type for the node. So after I chose "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin" for the specific node and then boot again , everything is fine.